# OpenCV column index skips rows when using 16-bit PGM (C++ interface)

Tags: opencv, indexing, 16-bit

Having a strange problem. I wrote a couple of functions to convert from an mat into a 2D int array and vice versa. I first wrote 3 channel 8 bit versions which work fine, but the 16-bit grayscale versions seem to be skipping indices on one of the dimensions.

Basically every second row is blank. (Only every second one is written to.) The only thing I can think is that it has something to do with the 16 bit representation.

The following is the code:

```
            // Convert a Mat image to a standard int array
            void matToArrayGS(cv::Mat imgIn, unsigned int **array)
            {
                int i, j;

                for(i=0; i<imgIn.rows; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<imgIn.cols; j++)
                    array[i][j]=imgIn.at<unsigned int>(i,j);
                }
            }

            // Convert an array into a Greyscale Mat image
            void arrayToMatGS(unsigned int **arrayin, cv::Mat imgIn)
            {
                int i, j;

                for(i=0; i<imgIn.rows; i++)
                {
                    for(j=0; j<imgIn.cols; j++)
                    imgIn.at<unsigned int>(i,j)=arrayin[i][j];
                }
            }
```

I can't help thinking it has something to do with the 16 bit representation in Mat but I can't find info on this. It's strange also that it works fine in one dimension and not the other....

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by "unsigned int" usage. Try "unsigned short" for 16 bits grayscale image.

Comment: Absolutely bang on! I don't know why I keep thinking of regular ints as 16-bit. Too much microcontroller action methinks. Thanks!!!